# Changing structure of a matrix file

Tags: linux, matrix

I have a matrix like data in tab separated text file. For example:

```
     a    b    c    d
a    0.1  0.5  0.3  0.0
b    0.9  0.2  0.4  0.7
c    0.2  0.0  0.6  0.5
d    0.0  0.5  0.3  0.1
```

I want this matrix data in tsv file such that 1st column is row index, 2nd column is column index and 3rd column is the value. For example the first 4 lines be like:

```
a    a    0.1
a    b    0.5
a    c    0.3
a    d    0.0
```

My file is large. It is about 5000 X 5000 matrix; so the starting input file has ~5000 rows and 5000 columns.
I was thinking to do it through series of text processing steps but is there some better way to do it on linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now this looks like a job for awk:

```
awk '
  NR==1 { split($0, cols); next }
  { for(col in cols) {
      print $1, cols[col], $(col+1)
    }
  }' \
  matrix
```

This little awk program …

- Stores the column headers into variable `cols`. The line is split like awk would already do for other lines (split on whitespace). This is done by executing the first block only for the first line (`NR==1`). `next` skips all other statements and proceeds to the next line.
- For all other lines, it iterates through the columns extracted from the first line (`for (col in cols)`) and then prints the first column of the current line (`$1`, i.e. the row header), then prints the column header (`cols[col]`), and finally prints the corresponding cell for the current row+column combination.

Comment: It really helped. Thanks a lot! Trying to figure out how exactly this code is working. If possible, can I get a very brief description. Thank you.

Comment: @Ali_A423 extended answer with description